# Adding functionality to jQuery UI Datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm getting to grips with the superb jQuery UI Datepicker.

I'm trying to show a calendar which defaults to Jan-to-Dec of the current year, but allows users to navigate backwards and forwards through the years.

It has other complexities - for instance the user selects weeks rather than days; in due course,  the idea is that it will provide navigation for completing weekly timesheets, highlighting which timesheets have been completed/submitted/approved - but that's for another day...

Right now, I can show a full year, and highlight on a week-by-week basis, but I can't incorporate the other requirements, namely:

1. navigate backwards and forwards through the years
2. Set the default to 'Jan-to-Dec of the current year', rather than 'Jan-to-Dec of 2016'
3. (less important) give it all a more compact appearance

With not inconsiderable assistance from others, here's what I have...

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var startDate;
    var endDate;

    var selectCurrentWeek = function() {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            $('.week-picker').find('.ui-datepicker-current-day a').addClass('ui-state-active')
        }, 1);
    }

    $('.week-picker').datepicker( {
        stepMonths: 12,
        showOtherMonths: true,
        selectOtherMonths: true,
        showWeek: true,
        numberOfMonths: [4, 3],
        minDate: new Date(2016, 1 -1, 1),
        maxDate: new Date(2016, 12 -1, 31),
        showButtonPanel: true,

        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            startDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay());
            endDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay() + 6);
            var dateFormat = inst.settings.dateFormat || $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat;
            $('#startDate').text($.datepicker.formatDate( dateFormat, startDate, inst.settings ));
            $('#endDate').text($.datepicker.formatDate( dateFormat, endDate, inst.settings ));

            selectCurrentWeek();
        },
        beforeShowDay: function(date) {
            var cssClass = '';
            if(date >= startDate && date <= endDate)
                cssClass = 'ui-datepicker-current-day';
            return [true, cssClass];
        },
        onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, inst) {
            selectCurrentWeek();
        }
    });

    $('.week-picker .ui-datepicker-calendar tr').live('mousemove', function() { $(this).find('td a').addClass('ui-state-hover'); });
    $('.week-picker .ui-datepicker-calendar tr').live('mouseleave', function() { $(this).find('td a').removeClass('ui-state-hover'); });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

minDate and maxDate decides the range of dates that are be visible in the calendar. As your range covers the entire year you are not able to move to previous or next year.
There is no option provided to set default Jan - Dec of the year but we can made some changes to the code to get that view.
However there is inconsistency while navigating to previous or next year in jQuery UI version 1.12.
I've tried with jQuery UI 1.11.4 and jQuery 1.12.4 and it works.

```
$(function() {
    var startDate;
    var endDate;

    var selectCurrentWeek = function() {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            $('.week-picker').find('.ui-datepicker-current-day a').addClass('ui-state-active')
        }, 1);
    }

    $('.week-picker').datepicker( {
        stepMonths: 12,
        showOtherMonths: true,
        selectOtherMonths: true,
        showWeek: true,
        numberOfMonths: [4, 3],
        showCurrentAtPos: new Date().getMonth(), //Shows the calendar from Jan to Dec
        showButtonPanel: true,

        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            startDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay());
            endDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay() + 6);
            var dateFormat = inst.settings.dateFormat || $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat;
            $('#startDate').text($.datepicker.formatDate( dateFormat, startDate, inst.settings ));
            $('#endDate').text($.datepicker.formatDate( dateFormat, endDate, inst.settings ));

            selectCurrentWeek();
        },
        beforeShowDay: function(date) {
            var cssClass = '';
            if(date >= startDate && date <= endDate)
                cssClass = 'ui-datepicker-current-day';
            return [true, cssClass];
        },
        onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, inst) {
            selectCurrentWeek();
        },
        beforeShow: function(date,inst){
            // shows the calendar view from jan to dec of the selected year
            if($( ".week-picker" ).datepicker( "getDate" ) != null){ // donot run on the first instance
                $( ".week-picker" ).datepicker( "option", "showCurrentAtPos", inst.selectedMonth );
            }
        }
    });

    $('.week-picker .ui-datepicker-calendar tr').live('mousemove', function() { $(this).find('td a').addClass('ui-state-hover'); });
    $('.week-picker .ui-datepicker-calendar tr').live('mouseleave', function() { $(this).find('td a').removeClass('ui-state-hover'); });
});
```

check the output here: https://jsbin.com/zopuke

Comment: Hi. Thanks for this; I've not responded sooner because there's quite a lot to digest. There's still a few things I need to adjust, but your implementation is definitely a substantial improvement